# Can't Upload images with Clean (English) filenames Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, upload, media-library

I am facing this strange issue - I can't upload images with clean file names in wordpress media library -- [i get this blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AW1S.jpg)

i can upload an image and everything works fine if the filename is in numbers e.g. 12321.jpg

[image]

but if i rename the same file to good-image.jpg and then upload it, the file gets uploaded but i see a blank grey thumbnail, even the attachment page is blank, however i do see the image when i edit it.

[image]

i have tried everything available on the internet. please help

Comment: give the permission to the uploads folder 744 it may seem permission issue

Comment: Hey i have already tried, updating permissions, relocating upload folder, clearing cache, disabling plugins, checking wp-config and htaccess …everything seems fine…ive tried every trick available on the internet.